# Airflow Task unexpected keyword Issue

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I have a python operator.

```
PythonOperator(
            task_id="getData",
            python_callable=getData,
            op_kwargs={
                "params": {
                    "days": 1,
                    "limit": 10
                }
            },
            provide_context=True,
        )
```

I have set the provide_context to True as i need data to be sent to other task.
I have the function where i want to pass just the **params** not **kwargs**.

```
  def getData(params):
        return params
```

I am getting an error upon running as:

**TypeError: getData() got an unexpected keyword argument 'conf'**

When i pass **kwargs and extract the params from it, it works fine but i do not want to pass kwargs just the params, what can be done for that?

Comment: Read the section titled [How to pass parameters to PythonOperator in Airflow](https://marclamberti.com/blog/airflow-pythonoperator/)

Answer (score 0):

Referring to official documentation at [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/python.html#templating):

> When you set the provide_context argument to True, Airflow passes in an additional set of keyword arguments

If you just want to pass the params to function, turn the `provide_context` False. `provide_context` is for Dag related meta information. This can be used in xcomm and to access configs.